# Problem in eclipse configuring tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

I have trouble when I want to configure eclipse. This error appears, but I dont know where is my problem. I copied `apache-tomcat-7.0.5` folder in `E:\Java` folder, where is java installed.

> Tomcat requires a Java SDK in order to compile JSP files. Ensure that the JRE preference settings point to an SDK install location.

Comment: "Tomcat requires a Java SDK" - that's not true. Tomcat has its own compiler, it only needs the JRE.

Comment: Thank you. I solved this problem but there apear new problem when I want configure web service.

Comment: Thank you. I solved this problem but there apear new problem when I want configure web service. Problem is: The Apache Axis2 Web service runtime in Tomcat v7.0 Server does not support the service project axis2service Please help.